# Cannot SSH to Azure VM: no kex alg

Tags: ssh, azure-vm

I have followed this tutorial (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial), but get the error "no kex alg", when I try to connect. Have tried to do the fixes suggested in

- [Vagrant ssh prompts 'no kex alg' and I'm unable to connect to the virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953537/vagrant-ssh-prompts-no-kex-alg-and-im-unable-to-connect-to-the-virtual-machin)

Any suggestions? Please see error log below.

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Fd3.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcQjg.png]

Answer (score 1):

OPEN THE PORT 22 in your Vm
so to this you have to go to your VM in AZURE and then networking and you will find all of the ports
so what you have to do it just open the ssh port 22
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WlW8.png)

this link it will be very useful to you because it's explaining how to open the port 22 from AZURE
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal
and for manage ssh public key with vm you can check this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sshkey?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32701446)

Comment: Using links is not okay, copy-paste-ing the content would be better and use links for reference.